# set map center to specific layer GeoExt 3.1.0

Tags: openlayers, geoext, sql-view

Using GeoExt 3.1.0, OpenLayers 4.4.1 and ExtJS 6.2.0.

I'm trying to make my first GIS web app and I am stuck trying to get the map to load with one of my layers in the center. While researching I was made to understand that this was achieved setting the view's `extent`. In my case I'm loading my tiles from geoserver and using one of its services to get the capabilities and thus its extent. The problem is I am not getting any errors but the map is not centering on the desired location `EPSG:3795`, but somewhere in the middle of the Atlantic, halfway between Leeward Antilles and Cabo Verde. Here is the code in full:

```
Ext.require([
    'GeoExt.component.Map',
    'GeoExt.data.store.LayersTree'
]);
var mapComponent;
var mapPanel;
var treePanel;
var descriptionPanel;

Ext.application({
    name: 'BasicTree',
    launch: function() {
        var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities', {mode: 'cors'}).then(function(response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function(text) {
            var result = parser.read(text);
            var extent = getEX_GeographicBoundingBox(result);
            console.log(extent);
            var extentTransform = ol.proj.transform(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
            console.log(extentTransform);
            var layers = [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
                        params: {'LAYERS': 'ws_geodeleg:prov'},
                        serverType: 'geoserver'
                    })
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
                        params: {'LAYERS': 'ws_geodeleg:muni'},
                        serverType: 'geoserver'
                    })
                })
            ];

            var view = new ol.View({
                center: ol.extent.getCenter(extentTransform),
                zoom: 5
            });

            var map = new ol.Map({
                layers: layers,
                view: view
            });

            mapComponent = Ext.create('GeoExt.component.Map', {
                map: map
            });

            var treeStore = Ext.create('GeoExt.data.store.LayersTree', {
                layerGroup: map.getLayerGroup()
            });

            treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
                title: 'Tree Example',
                viewConfig: {
                    plugins: {ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'}
                },
                store: treeStore,
                rootVisible: false,
                border: false
            });

            descriptionPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                contentEl: 'content-el',
                title: 'Description',
                border: false,
            });

            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                width: '100%',
                height: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                title: 'title',
                layout: {
                    type: 'border'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'South Region is resizable',
                        region: 'south',
                        height: '20%',
                        split: true,
                        collapsible: true,
                        margin: '0 5 5 5'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'West Region is collapsible',
                        region: 'west',
                        margin: '5 0 0 5',
                        width: '15%',
                        split: true,
                        collapsible: true,
                        id: 'west-region-container',
                        items: [treePanel, descriptionPanel]
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Mapa',
                        region: 'center',
                        margin: '5 5 0 0',
                        items: [mapComponent]
                    }],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The `getEX_GeographicBoundingBox` function:

```
function getEX_GeographicBoundingBox(result){
    return result.Capability.Layer.Layer.find(l => l.Name === 'ws_geodeleg:prov').EX_GeographicBoundingBox;
}
```

In case it's useful:

```
console.log(extent) --> [-80.80061652889158, 21.94540368776222, -79.2899712690279, 23.222106568708703]

console.log(extentTransform) --> [-8994683.487778775, 2504971.556251283, -79.2899712690279, 23.222106568708703]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`var extentTransform = ol.proj.transform(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');`

with

`var extentTransform = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');`

It wasn't giving any errors or anything, it just placed my view's center in the middle of the Atlantic. Checking the docs for the millionth time I noticed the other function and it worked perfectly.